# How to play list of songs in server side and send only the lyrics of the current song to the client side in php?

Tags: php, media, jscript

This is an small package for an office staffs. I am trying to develop a `php` application that should run `mp3` song on server and send the lyrics of the current song(only) to the client side. I need to play list of songs randomly in server and the lyrics of current song(running on server) should be sent on client side. For this I have done following things(all things are done in localhost)::

```
  database name:album
  table name: song(id,name,lyrics,status)
  Note: this is manual update done by admin::
  filename: - admin.php
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  mysqli_query($con,"update album set status=0");//all song status cleared
  mysqli_query($con,"update album set status=1 where id=$id");//status with value 1 is playing on               server
```

filename: - client.php

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" >
    <body align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    //echo $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select name,lyrics from album where album.status=1");
    //echo last_query();die;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<h1>".$row['name']."</h1>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<h3>".$row['lyrics']."</h3>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, everything is okay with above code but the admin should update each time which song is playing in server. I need this task automated. For this, i need to play list of songs(from database) to be played and their corresponding lyrics in client side. What to do?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Songs must be played on client side.You should change the logic.

Comment: no, song should be played on server side.  @Oyeme , it's an app for small office for only one room or in a hall. song is played on server and every client listen that, no any client has the right to change the song or do anything, so. and the client can only read the lyrics of that song..

Comment: Just have a look http://ampache.org/

Comment: Are you talking about streaming?

Comment: Does the server actually need to play the music file, or simply parse it?

Comment: @antony, no it's not about streaming. song is in server and should be played in server, but the lyrics of that song only, i am repeating it that only lyrics of that song should be sent to client.

Comment: @Mark Baker, server need to play the music file, no parsing..

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/41780/how-can-i-batch-extract-id3-lyrics-metadata-from-mp3-files might be a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (it uses the mp3 player mpg123 but you can use anything else (cvlc, mplayer, ...) :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$con=mysqli_connect(...);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
while(true){
  mysqli_query($con,"update album set status=0");
  $res = mysqli_query($con,"select id, file from album order by rand() limit 1");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  mysqli_query($con,"update album set status=1 where id=".$row['id']);
  passthru('mpg123 '.escapeshellarg($row['file']));
}
```

This script is meant to be executed from the command line (not with the web server)

Comment: how to use the passthru function in windows? I need to play one song after another.., for this I used $file='./music/'.$row['name'];
  echo "<embed src =\"$file\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>"; But at one time only one song is played and for another song, i need to refresh the page?? How to play next song automatically after another song..?

Comment: you could try with exec() or system() instead. But I don't understand because you said "song should be played on server side." and the use of <embed> is client side